# Get the first next certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to get the first next div selector , so i can its css , but i can manage to do it,for some reason it returns an object.I may have wrong knowledge about 'next' .

HTML:

```
<div class="bla" onclick="Find(this.className);"></div>
<p></p>
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function Find(x){
   $('.'+x).next('div:first').css({'display': 'none'});
   console.log($('.'+x).next('div:first'));
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Say in a simple way.

Comment: @PraveenKumar , i thought i said it pretty clear , i'm trying to get the first next div className , when i trigger the find() function

Comment: `.next()` functions returns jQuery object  upon which we can call all the jquery functions. eg. `.css()`. *ref:Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.- http://api.jquery.com/next/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use next as it will search only the next sibling element

```js
function Find(x) {
  $(x).nextAll('div').first().css({
    'display': 'none'
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bla" onclick="Find(this);">d</div>
<p></p>
<div class="first">f</div>
<div class="second">s</div>
```

---

Since you are using jQuery, try to use jQuery event handlers